# Ошибка времени выполнения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: массивы, pascal

Программа должна рассчитывать значения некоторых функций (в данном случае F(x)=sin(x)*cos(x) и G(x)=(x-1)^3). Но в 23 строке (указал комментарием) появляется ошибка, указанная в теме. Также в строке 24 и 32 (также указано) выводится ошибка "Параметр цикла for в PascalABC.NET должен описываться в заголовке цикла". Заранее благодарю!

```
program lr2;
var A : real; //Левая граница отрезка
    B : real; //Правая граница отрезка
    N : integer; //Количество интервалов
    i : integer; //Переменная цикла
    h : real; //Величина шага
    x : array of real; //Массив аргументов функции
    F : array of real; //Массив значений F(x)
    G : array of real; //Массив значений G(x)
    
begin
  write ('Введите значение первой точки: A = ');
  readln (A);
  write ('Введите значение второй точки: B = ');
  readln (B);
  if A>=B then writeln ('Ошибка ввода отрезка, A должно быть строго меньше B!')
  else begin
  write ('Введите количество инетрвалов: N = ');
  readln (N);
  if N<=0 then writeln ('Ошибка ввода колличества интервалов, N должно быть cтрого больше 0!')
  else begin
  h:=(B - A)/N;
  x[1]:=1; // СТРОКА 23
  for i:= 1 to N do //строка 24
      begin
      F[i]:=sin(x[i])*cos(x[i]);
      G[i]:=Power((x[i]-1),3);
      x[i+1]:= A + h;
      end;
writeln ('┌───────┬───────┬───────┐');
writeln ('│  x   │ F(x) │ G(x) │');
for i:=1 to N do // строка 32
  begin
  writeln ('├───────┼───────┼───────┤');
  writeln ('│  ',x[i],'  │  ',F[i],'  │  ',G[i],'  │');  
  end;
  end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

ок, объявили динамический, а не статический массив

```
x : array of real
```

но

> When declaring a variable of a dynamic array type, the initial length
> of the array is zero. The actual length of the array must be set with
> the standard SetLength function, which will allocate the necessary
> memory to contain the array elements on the heap.

кто массиву размер то задаст перед тем как в него что-то писать?

https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu14.html

Comment: Я пытался задать размер массива, выдаётся та же ошибка. Даже так, мне нужно задать размер массива, равный N

Comment: @Like_N, ну справку то можно почитать по [массивам](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/Types/dynamicarrays.html) и [циклам](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/Operators/for.html)? Кроме того, убедитесь что вы используете последнюю версию паскаля.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  var A := ReadReal('Введите значение первой точки: A =');
  var B := ReadReal('Введите значение второй точки: B =');
  if A >= B then
    Print('Ошибка ввода отрезка, A должно быть строго меньше B!')
  else
  begin
    write();
    var N := ReadInteger('Введите количество интервалов: N =');
    if N <= 0 then
      Print('Ошибка ввода количества интервалов, N должно быть cтрого больше 0!')
    else
    begin
      var x := new real[N + 1];
      var F := new real[N + 1];
      var G := new real[N + 1];
      var h := (B - A) / N;
      for var i := 0 to N do
      begin
        x[i] := A + i * h;
        F[i] := Sin(x[i]) * Cos(x[i]);
        G[i] := (x[i] - 1) ** 3
      end;
      Println('┌───────┬────────┬────────┐');
      Println('│   x   │  F(x)  │  G(x)  │');
      for var i := 0 to N do
      begin
        Println('├───────┼────────┼────────┤');
        Writeln('│', x[i]:7:2, '│', F[i]:8:4, '│', G[i]:8:4, '│')
      end;
      Println('└───────┴────────┴────────┘');
    end
  end
end.

Введите значение первой точки: A =  2.8
Введите значение второй точки: B =  4.9
Введите количество интервалов: N =  5
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐ 
│   x   │  F(x)  │  G(x)  │ 
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   2.80│ -0.3156│  5.8320│
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   3.22│  0.0781│ 10.9410│
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   3.64│  0.4199│ 18.3997│
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   4.06│  0.4824│ 28.6526│
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   4.48│  0.2241│ 42.1442│
├───────┼────────┼────────┤ 
│   4.90│ -0.1832│ 59.3190│
└───────┴────────┴────────┘
```